# Make a list of second elements from list of tuples of length 2 without using loops: Python

Tags: python

I want to write a succinct and elegant code for the following problem:

Assuming that I have a list of tuples:

```
[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ....., (xn,yn)].
```

I want to create a list `[y1, y2, ....,yn]` **without using the loops.**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Anything that will accomplish this *will* loop somewhere, either in python code or in native code.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
>>> x = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> x2 = [k[1] for k in x]
>>> x2
[2, 4, 6]
```

The [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) does a loop internally, but you didn't have to type the words `for` or `while`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zip` to [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the sequence from "N tuples each of size 2" to "2 tuples each of size N", and then slice off everything but the second result:

```
seq = [("z", "a"), ("y", "b"), ("x", "c")]
print zip(*seq)[1]
```

Result:

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: Thank you. This is an elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

mtrw has the right idea in standard Python. However, if you'd like to make the jump directly to numpy, I highly recommend it. It allows for all sort of indexing:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([(1,2),(3,4),(4,5)])

x[:,1]
```

Result:

```
array([2,4,6])
```

Edit:
In addition to this simple indexing, you can loop over the arrays like any list, and has all the same properties plus [more](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). 
Edit 2: vanilla -> standard